# Heroku cannot find wsgi app

Tags: python, django, heroku, wsgi, procfile

I am trying to deploy a Django app on Heroku. The deployment works but when I run the web page I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named hello.wsgi
```

My Proc file reads as: web:

```
gunicorn hello.wsgi --log-file -
```

I would appreciate suggestions if anyone knows why I get this error.

Comment: Did you try to add this `gunicorn hello.wsgi:application`?

Comment: What is in the top level directory? Do you have a sub directory called ``hello``, with a ``wsgi.py`` file in it? If using Python 2.7, does the sub directory have a ``__init__.py`` file in it?